# Is this block of code efficient?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database-design

I am trying to assign a variable tagcolor only if it already exists in the database. This code queries the DB twice if the color is present, once to determine if it does indeed exist and another to actually assign it.

If it doesn't exist I just want to assign tagcolor to the user provided color.

```
if Tagmap.where("name = ? AND user_id = ?", tag, current_user.id).first.present?
  tagcolor = Tagmap.where("name = ? AND user_id = ?", tag, current_user.id).first.color
else
  tagcolor = params[:color].downcase
end
```

Can I reduce this block so I just query the DB once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided you're on Rails 4, you can do:

```
tagcolor = Tagmap.find_by(name: tag, user: current_user).try(:color) || params[:color].downcase
```

Similar (but not that pretty) construction is possible in Rails 3:

```
tagcolor = Tagmap.find_by_name_and_user(tag, current_user).try(:color) || params[:color].downcase
```

Comment: I prefer your solution :)

Comment: Thank you!! Your solution worked. I'll mark it correct after my timer runs out :)